# Why doesn't Javascript put some respeck on my input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm currently working on a budget software and I've come across this strange bug. First of here is my code:

```
<label class="label label-success">Choose your budget</label><br/><br/>

<div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
<input type="number" min="10" max="25000" maxlength="5" step="10" class="form-control" id="Input-budget" placeholder="Amount" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" onchange="budCalculate(this.value)">
```

this is the output line:

```
<li>
  <strong>
  Total cost: <span id="cost_eur">€0.00 </span> (<span id="cost_usd" class="small">$0.00</span>)
  </strong>
</li>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
function budCalculate(budget_amount) {
  var budget = budget_amount;
  cost_eur.innerHTML = "€"+((budget).toFixed(2);
  cost_usd.innerHTML = "$"+ (budget * 1.13 ).toFixed(2);
}
```

It's supposed to put the value of the input on the output line.

The `onkeyup` is to prevent people from typing letters.

I've tried all kinds of variations and the funny thing is almost the same identical code is working on a similar looking page.

Why doesn't JavaScript put respeck on my value?

Comment: The function budCalculate is called ? Please try using a console.log or whatever inside.

Comment: It says:  (budget).toFixed is not a function. (In '(budget).toFixed(2)', '(budget).toFixed' is undefined) but that was because i forgot a '(' before budget. The code is still not working after that fix tho.

Comment: Hmm nope, it says : TypeError: budget.toFixed is not a function. (In 'budget.toFixed(2)', 'budget.toFixed' is undefined)

Comment: The console log says; ReferenceError: Can't find variable: budCalculate <-- referencing to the onchange

Comment: @jo8691 respeck is [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jLT7GQYNhI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that `budget` is not a Number Object. `this.value` will pass a String Object. I would advise changing your function:

```
function budCalculate(budget_amount) {
  var budget = 0;
  console.log(typeof budget_amount);
  budget = parseFloat(budget_amount);
  cost_eur.innerHTML = "€" + budget.toFixed(2);
  cost_usd.innerHTML = "$" + ( budget * 1.13 ).toFixed(2);
  return budget;
}
```

You can now see what type of object is being passed. The `parseFloat()` should correct the issue.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bqjg50sb/

Comment: Boom thats it, you won, case closed, thank you very much!

Comment: @luissimo glad to hear it.